# Representation of general Markov Chain

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space (state space) and let $T\colon X \times [0,1] \to X$ be measurable function that represents a dynamic in $X$ that has a parameter $u \in [0,1]$ (for a fix $u\in [0,1]$ $T(\cdot,u)$ is deterministic dynamical system). With this we can construct a Markov Chain by taking an i.i.d. series $(U_n) \sim $Unif$[0,1]$ and define inductively the process $Z$ as follows:
$$Z_0 \sim \mu, \quad Z_{n+1} = T(Z_n,U_{n+1}) $$
where $\mu$ is a probability measure on $X$ (initial distribution).

Is easy to see that $Z$ is a Markov chain and we can more or less explicitly calculate his transition kernel:

Let $x \in X$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}$
\begin{align*}
K(x,A) 
&  = P(Z_{n+1} \in A \  | \ Z_n = x ) \\
&  = P(T(Z_n,U_{n+1}) \in A \ | \ Z_n = x) \\
& = P(T(x,U_{n+1}) \in A) \\
& = \lambda\left(\left[T(x,\cdot) \right]^{-1}(A) \right) \\
& = [T(x,\cdot)]^* \lambda (A)
\end{align*}

Then $K(x,\cdot)$ is the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure by $T(x,\cdot)$.

Here is my question:

Is it posible to construct a function like $T$ above for a general Markov Kernel?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**A partial answer:** If $(X,\mathcal B)$ is a [standard Borel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Standard_Borel_spaces_and_Kuratowski_theorems), then such a $T$ exists. For in this case the measurable space $(X,\mathcal B)$ is ismorphic to $(\Bbb R,\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$; let $\varphi: X\to\Bbb R$ be this isomorphism.  Let $\mu_x(B):=K(x,\varphi^{-1}(B))$ denote the push-forward of $K(x,\cdot)$, and let $F_x$ be the associated distribution function. As is well-known, if $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ then $F_x^{-1}(U)$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu_x$. (Here $F_x^{-1}(u):=\sup\{t: F_x(t)\le u\}$ for $u\in[0,1]$.) It's not hard to check that $(x,u)\mapsto F_x^{-1}(u)$ is $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal B([0,1])/\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$-measurable. Finally, move things back to $X$ by setting $T(x,u):=\varphi^{-1}(F_x^{-1}(u))$.